# While calculating income value is getting is retrieving as 0

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core-mvc, dapper, npgsql

I wanted to calculate `sum(amount)` between dates by using the query as shown below.

My controller:

```
public IActionResult AllTransactionsList(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    using (NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        List<Transaction> expenseLists = new List<Transaction>();

        List<Transaction>? transactions2 = connection.Query<Transaction>("SELECT SUM(t.amount) as Income " +
                            "FROM transaction AS t " +
                            "INNER JOIN account AS a ON t.account_id = a.account_id " +
                            "WHERE t.date BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate AND a.type = 'income'", new { startDate = startDate, endDate = endDate }) as List<Transaction>;

        expenseLists.AddRange(transactions2);

        var model = new AllTransactionViewModel();
        model.ExpenseLists = expenseLists;

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

`Transaction` model class:

```
public class Transaction
{
    public int Transaction_Id { get; set; }
    public string Account_Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public int Income { get; set; }
    public int Expense { get; set; }
}
```

`AllTransactionViewModel`:

```
public class AllTransactionViewModel
{
    public List<Transaction> IncomeLists { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<div class="float-child">
    <div class="green">
        <label><h2>INCOME:</h2></label>
        @foreach(var item in Model.IncomeLists)
        {
            <h3>@item.Income</h3>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

There is nothing wrong with query or database.

When calculating the income and displaying I am getting **0** value, what went wrong can anyone help me?

Comment: Share some sample data please

Comment: Thanks, sure I am adding some data pics in here: [link1](https://ibb.co/jyRkkJz)
 [link2](https://ibb.co/CB06Gs9)

Comment: No change, I have tried adding... but there is nothing wrong with query

Comment: @prem Put the last 3 statements outside the using block and try again

Answer (score 1):

You sum income data in the sql query. Parsing data with long type will solve this problem, i think.

```
  long incomeSum= connection.Query<long>("SELECT SUM(t.amount) as Income " +
                        "FROM transaction AS t " +
                        "INNER JOIN account AS a ON t.account_id = a.account_id " +
                        "WHERE t.date BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate AND a.type = 'income'", new { startDate = startDate, endDate = endDate });
```

Comment: That will fail. You cannot put a List<Transaction> into long. Drop ` as List<Transaction>` and use QuerySingle.

Comment: you are right, i've forgotten deleting the conversion. thanks. @PalleDue